# jquery validate - fail on radio

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that's checked by jquery validate.  The field that's causing some issue looks like this:

```
<label>Select an Account Type<</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="accountType" value="1" id="accountType_C"><label id="accountType_C" for="accountType_C">Coder</label>
<input type="radio" name="accountType" value="0" id="accountType_S"><label id="accountType_S" for="accountType_S">Surreptitious Ninja</label>
```

All other fields in the form validate appropriately with the exception of the one above.  Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.  There's about 12 other fields that get validated with no issue.  I've double checked the validate for duplicate declarations but there are none.

Here's the validate function:

```
$("#regForm").validate({

    rules: {

        accountType: "required"

    },

    messages: {

        accountType: "You must select an account type"

    }

});
```

Thanks much!

Comment: try using rules:{ accountType:{required: true} }

Comment: thanks. the brackets did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#regForm").validate({

        rules: {

                accountType: "checked"

        },

        messages: {

                accountType: "You must select an account type"

        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record ;)

```
$("#regForm").validate({
    rules: {
        accountType: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        accountType: "You must select an account type"
    }
});
```